# how to set two different passwords for screen lock and factory reset

Tags: factory-reset

I want to set up my android phone such that it should not have any screen lock but it should ask for a password when i try to factory reset it.

I have tried so many websites for this trick but could not find any solution yet.

Comment: Please specify phone model and software version.

Comment: You can't achieve the objective  without rooting. If you've a rooted device, you can use Tasker in combination with [ProtectedApps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.protectedapps) to have separate but still a native lock screen. Problem is, the latter acts on every part of app, while we want to lockdown only a specific part of UI (an activity here). Perhaps, you can kindly ask its developer to implement lockdown at Activity level.